# A problem occurred starting process 'command 'jruby''

Tags: rvm, jruby, warbler

I have a Gradle [task](https://github.com/nordic-institute/X-Road/blob/8d0f04a02c173951266d45f6a8547ee80521649d/src/center-service/build.gradle#L71) from X-road project:

```
task runModelTests(dependsOn: [updateSQLiteDbSchema], type: Exec) {
commandLine = ['jruby', '-S', 'rake', 'test:units', 'RAILS_ENV=test']
}
```

The task is failed with following exception:

```
Could not start 'jruby'
Cannot run program "jruby" (in directory "/home/virtdev/IdeaProjects/X-Road/src/center-service"): error=2, No such file or directory
error=2, No such file or directory
```

But I have jruby -v:

```
warning: --1.9 ignored
jruby 9.2.9.0 (2.5.7) 2019-10-30 458ad3e Eclipse OpenJ9 VM openj9-0.26.0 on 11.0.11+9 +jit [linux-x86_64]
```

rvm -v:

```
rvm 1.29.12
```

Ubuntu 20.04

Update:
I don't have a problem with Gradle.
The problem is `jruby: No suck file or directory -- warble (LoadError)` when I run `jruby -S warble` cmd
in `/src/central-server` dir.

Similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071575/jruby-warbler-results-in-no-such-file-to-load-bundler-dep-proxy)

Comment: There is a strong connection between the error and $PATH variable. I can't properly explain, but for some reason JRuby dependence desperate for $PATH and it become obvious in a separate terminal session.

Comment: `warning: --1.9 ignored` is interesting to me, do you have an alias set up for `jruby`? You can check this with the `alias` command in the shell.

Comment: Hi @msbit thanks for your comments. I check `alias` and I don't have alias for `jruby`. On the other hand I don't have `warning: --1.9 ignored` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually install `warbler` after that script failed with another dependency error.
In the end I completely reinstalled `RVM` with and it helped.